# MacBook Pro late 2012, want 2 external monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I know this question has been asked a million times but I can't seem to find the right answer for my MBP late 2012.

I have 2 monitors. One connects to my Thunderbolt via a Thunderbolt to HDMI cable. It works fine.

I bought the Elgato Thunderbolt 2 dock believing that I could plug in my Thunderbolt cable into this and then plug my second monitor into the HDMI port. Of course it doesn't work and I'm pretty sure it's not going to work....

Any thoughts on how I can connect 2 monitors? Both have VGA and HDMI ports.

Comment: BTW: according to everymac there is no non-Retina MBP Late 2012! The Elgato website clearly states:  *Dual displays are supported when using HDMI and a Thunderbolt™ or Thunderbolt™ 2 display.* So either get a TB display if your MBP is a Retina or a [USB display-link gadget](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-unibody-faq/macbook-pro-air-how-to-connect-a-second-external-third-display.html).

Answer (score 2):

Mactracker lists a 2012 MBP as a 13 inch Retina model (MD212LL/A, MacBookPro10,2) with an Intel GPU and using up to 1 GB of shared memory.

Mactracker also says:

> Supports an HDMI-compatible device while using one Thunderbolt
>   display or support for two Thunderbolt displays

If the model you put down is indeed this one, then you'll need 2 Thunderbolt displays. Or you can run one monitor through the HDMI connection and another one through the Thunderbolt connection.

What this model can't do is run two HDMI monitors which it sounds like you're trying to do.

I highly recommend both everymac.com and Mactracker as sources of info on older Macs. Both have a wealth of information which would have given you the answer(s) you've been looking for.